# How to save an Int64 variable using NSCoding

Tags: ios, swift, int64

In my iOS app I have a number variable that starts at 0 but could conceivably end up being 3,000,000,000,000.

If I declare it as an Int it will be fine on 64 bit devices because the Int type will refer to an Int64 type (max value 9,223,372,036,854,775,807). But on 32 bit devices, the Int type will refer to an Int32 type which has a max value of 2,147,483,647. That's too small, obviously.

So how best to approach this problem and make it run properly on 32 bit devices?

If I understand correctly, I can declare the variable as an Int64 and it will be fine on both 32 bit and 64 bit devices:

```
  var myNumber:Int64 = 0
```

However, I use NSCoding to persist my data and I am getting error messages when trying to encode and decode it:

```
myNumber = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("MyNumber")
```

Error: Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int64'

```
aCoder.encodeInteger(myNumber, forKey: "MyNumber")
```

Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Int64' to expected argument type 'Int'

So how can I use NSCoding with this variable? Or is there a better way to handle my large number than declaring it as an Int64?

Comment: Use `encodeObject` or use two separate integers.

Comment: `NSCoder` has `encodeInt64` and `decodeInt64` methods

Comment: Thanks dan, I didn't know that. If you put that as the answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let exBytesVideo = aDecoder.decodeInt64ForKey("myInt64Number")
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeInt64(self.expectedBytesVideo, forKey: "myInt64Number")
}
```